# Why "column width" is set to a different value?

Tags: python, python-3.x, excel, openpyxl

I'm trying to set the dimensions (height & width) of 100 × 100 cells in an already existing Excel workbook but it fails to set the width of columns to the correct value (though row heights are set to correct values). I'm trying to set the column width to `10` but after opening the actual Excel file, the column widths turn out to be `9.29`. What am I doing wrong?

```
from os import name
import openpyxl
from openpyxl.descriptors.base import DateTime
from openpyxl.utils import get_column_letter
import datetime


def format_wb(wb):
    for ws in wb.sheetnames:
        for i in range(1, 101):
            wb[ws].column_dimensions[get_column_letter(i)].width = 10
            wb[ws].row_dimensions[i].height = 20

    return wb


def main():
    file_name = "test"
    wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(f"{file_name}.xlsx")
    wb = format_wb(wb)
    wb.save(f"{file_name}.xlsx")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 2):

[EDIT] This, I think, is a more satisfying explanation:

"In Excel, xml stored values and values displayed for user should be different and depend on default font selected in theme (for Colibri difference is 0.7109375).

`openpyxl` does not load default font info and Excel files created by it use the same default font (Colibri 11).

So, for files saved using `openpyxl`, 0.7109375 is constant."

Source: https://foss.heptapod.net/openpyxl/openpyxl/-/issues/293

---

As far as I understand, nothing is wrong with your code.
Had the same problem recently, found empirically that if you want a column width equal to an integer number in Excel (10 in your case), you have to set it to that number + 0.71 with openpyxl (10.71 in your case).

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I'm doing for a while but that's a walk around the pitfall.